[boost::ext]sml understanding how the transition table syntax works
I play around a bit with [boost::ext]sml
The question is not how I can create and run state machines, it looks easy. But I want to know HOW this machinery is implemented and how it can work with the given code.
If I have code like this:
struct connect {
  int id{};
};
struct disconnect {};
struct interrupt {};

struct Disconnected {};
struct Connected {
  int id{};  /// per state data
};
struct Interrupted {
  int id{};  /// per state data
};

class data {
  using Self = data;

 public:
  explicit data(const std::string& address) : address{address} {}

  auto operator()() {
    using namespace boost::sml;

    const auto set = [](const auto& event, Connected& state) { state.id = event.id; };
    const auto update = [](Connected& src_state, Interrupted& dst_state) { dst_state.id = src_state.id; };

    return make_transition_table(
      * state<Disconnected> + event<connect>    / (set, &Self::print)    = state<Connected>
      , state<Connected>    + event<interrupt>  / (update, &Self::print) = state<Interrupted>
      , state<Interrupted>  + event<connect>    / (set, &Self::print)    = state<Connected>
      , state<Connected>    + event<disconnect> / (&Self::print)         = X
    );
  }

 private:
  void print(Connected& state) { std::cout << address << ':' << state.id << '\n'; };

  std::string address{};  /// shared data between states
};

taken from here
I have simply no idea how
    return make_transition_table(
      * state<Disconnected> + event<connect>    / (set, &Self::print)    = state<Connected>
      , state<Connected>    + event<interrupt>  / (update, &Self::print) = state<Interrupted>
      , state<Interrupted>  + event<connect>    / (set, &Self::print)    = state<Connected>
      , state<Connected>    + event<disconnect> / (&Self::print)         = X
    );

works?
My understanding is that state<Connected> is a type and not an object. How can operators like '+' work on types? If the syntax is with "hallo"_s notation, it looks clear, as this will return an object and we can continue with operator overloading until we have everything done. But with only the type is given?
Can someone help?

it's a variable template

@sehe Got it... found template < typename T> class struct; before, but this was in different namespace. But the line template <class T> constexpr typename front::state_sm<T>::type state{}; is the tricky part here... Thank you for being my classes :-)
